# Searching a occurrence of a pattern in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem: in a series of number say 4,2,3,6,5,1,3,4,2  i am looking for occurrence of a particular pattern as Low High and Low again. in this example
the result should be, 2 sequences of numbers,
first one 2,3,6,5,1 and the other one will be 3,4,2
Logic is :
4<2 No 2<3 Yes 3<6 No 6<5 No 5<1 No 1<3 Yes(basically looking for a series of multiple (Yes's No's and Yes's)
and
3<4 Yes and 4<2 No (if the last is No presiding a yes then it's a match too)
any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: the sequence shouldn't be overlapping in this case the result should be 2,3,6,5 and 1,3,4,2 1 shouldn't be counted...one more example: 6,4,5,3,2,1,4,6,2,3,4 result should be 4,5,3 and 1,4,6,2

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG` and `LEAD` to look at the previous/next values in the sequence and then work out the rate of change and rate of acceleration in the sequence values to find the minima in the sequence and aggregate between those rows:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/226)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH your_data ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM,
         COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 4,2,3,6,5,1,3,4,2 ) )
),
changes( id, value, gradient, acceleration ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         CASE
           WHEN nxt IS NULL THEN prv
           WHEN prv IS NULL THEN nxt
           WHEN prv = -nxt THEN 0
           WHEN nxt = 0    THEN prv
           WHEN prv = 0    THEN nxt
           ELSE nxt
         END,
         CASE
           WHEN nxt IS NULL THEN COALESCE( prv, 0 )
           WHEN prv IS NULL THEN nxt
           WHEN prv =  1 AND nxt IN (0,-1) THEN -1
           WHEN prv = -1 AND nxt IN (0, 1) THEN  1
           ELSE 0
         END
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           value,
           SIGN( value - LAG( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY id )  ) AS prv,
           SIGN( LEAD( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) - value ) AS nxt
    FROM   your_data
  )
),
minima ( id, value, gradient, acceleration, last_minima, next_minima ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         gradient,
         acceleration,
         LAST_VALUE(  CASE WHEN acceleration = 1 THEN id END ) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ),
         FIRST_VALUE( CASE WHEN acceleration = 1 THEN id END ) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
  FROM   changes
  ORDER BY id
)
SELECT ( SELECT LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY id )
         FROM   minima n
         WHERE  ( m.last_minima IS NULL OR m.last_minima <= n.id )
         AND    ( m.next_minima IS NULL OR m.next_minima >= n.id )
       ) As range
FROM   minima m
WHERE  gradient = 0
AND    acceleration = -1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/226/0)**:

```
|     RANGE |
|-----------|
| 2,3,6,5,1 |
|   1,3,4,2 |
```

*(Note: it is untested for consecutive equal values in the sequence)*